# Static location with nginx downloading file instead of showing response

Tags: nginx

I've read about this problem with php a numerous amount of times by now. I'm trying to get the basic of nginx since I almost exclusively used apache or iis.

I'm running a small debian 9 server and trying to figure out the basics of the nginx config.

the **nginx.conf** file is mostely untouched by me.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The **default.conf** file however is edited by me:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name 10.20.30.1;

    root /var/www;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

}
```

when accessing via IP, I get everything from my `/var/www` folder correctly loaded up with css files. So the including mime-type is working quite well.

after adding:

```
    location /greet {
          return 200 "Hello User!";
    }
```

to the server configuration I'm able to access `http://10.20.30.1/greet` but instead of displaying the message within the browser it's being downloaded as a file without extension, called greet with my message inside.

I found many simular problems like mine regarding php. In this case php shouldn't even be an issue by now.

Any advice would be very helpful.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `return` statement literally sends a text response with the default content type. If the browser does not understand how to present a given content type, it will offer to download the file.

You can tell the browser that it's plain text using the `default_type` directive.

For example:

```
location /greet {
    default_type text/plain;
    return 200 "Hello User!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tested it after your comment with Firefox and it worked as it was. Added the default type too, did what it's supposed to do